# How to delete a polygon in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a basic game in Tkinter that involves pressing a start button and making a shape appear which is working, then when you click on the shape it gets deleted and moved to a different random location.

I am getting `NameError: name 'square' is not defined` when I try to run it.

```
root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
can = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
can.pack(side=TOP)

def makeShape():
    xpos = random.randint(1, 400)
    ypos = random.randint(1, 400)
    square=can.create_polygon(xpos, ypos, xpos + 40, ypos, xpos + 40, ypos + 40, 
                              xpos, ypos + 40, fill="blue")
    can.tag_bind(square,"<Button-1>",deleteShape)

def deleteShape(event):
    can.delete(square)

but1 = Button(frame, text="Start", command=makeShape)
but1.grid(row=1, column=2)

frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why delete and recreate? The canvas has ways to move an object.

Comment: @BryanOakley perhaps that would be easier but i was struggling with move because of the random coordinates

Comment: Mike: The random coordinates shouldn't be a problem because when you move a Canvas item, all you need to supply is the amounts to move in the x and y directions (and the tag or id of the object).

Comment: @martineau so should i make it similar to the makeShape code above but replace create with move or will this cause the shape to move off the canvas or an error similar?

Comment: Since it's basically one line of code, `square.move(…)`, the way you do it won't affect whether it's "valid" or not. If you want to put in some checks for that, then making it a function would be best. To do that you may to need to keep track of its current location (`xpos` and `ypos`). Note your follow-on questions are getting too involved. Ask a new question if you have further problems.

Comment: @martineau ok sorry just one last thing the move function seems to move it a certain distance in the x and y direction is it possible instead to move it to a new location instead  of moving it by a certain amount if you understand what im saying?

Comment: Moving it to a new location, `xnew`, `ynew` from its current position `xpos`, `ypos`, is just `can.move(square, xnew-xpos, ynew-ypos)`. **Note** the syntax for the `move` call I mentioned previously was incorrect.

Comment: @martineau i think the method below is better as when i tried move like you stated it seems to move off the screen a lot

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you have submitted a post, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large ([under the CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Mike: Frequently deleting and recreating a Canvas widget will eventually use a lot of memory (which doesn't get reused) — that's why _updating_ an existing one would be better. Neither technique would result in the object moving offscreen more often if it's done correctly — i.e. you need to check and make sure that the new position is on the screen (and do something to correct it when it happens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `square` is a local variable inside `makeShape()`, so it cannot be accessed outside the function.

You can use `tags` option in `create_polygon()` instead.  If you want to move the square when it is clicked, `deleteShape()` is not necessary at all.  Just using `makeShape()` is enough:

```py
from tkinter import *
import random

root=Tk()
frame=Frame(root)
can = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
can.pack(side=TOP)

def makeShape():
    # delete existing square
    can.delete("square") 
    # create square at random position
    xpos = random.randint(1, 360)
    ypos = random.randint(1, 360)
    can.create_polygon(xpos, ypos, xpos+40, ypos, xpos+40, ypos+40, xpos, ypos+40,
                       fill="blue", tags="square")
    # call makeShape() when the square is clicked
    can.tag_bind("square", "<Button-1>", lambda e: makeShape())

but1 = Button(frame, text="Start", command=makeShape)
but1.grid(row=1, column=2)

frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Mike: This solution is better in the sense that it doesn't require using a global variable (although the tag name itself should probably be made a global **constant**).

Answer (score 1):

While it's not good practice, if you add line `global square` to `makeShape()` it will run as expected.

That's because if the name is assigned first time inside a block, it won't be visible to parent or sibling blocks.

There are alternatives, considered better for readability and more practical, but my suggestion is the quickest fix to your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, just out of interest what would you suggest to improve the readability of it?

Comment: @Mike:If you delete the shape, you will not be able to move it (obviously). Just making `square` a global variable won't affect the ability to move it otherwise.